# what is the correct typescript syntax for a static generator function with a yield return?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to write a static function on a class, which uses the generator/yield pattern.  Can somebody give me a code example of what the method signature syntax looks like?  Specifically, I am trying to write a fibonacci generator, but any number generator will do.

```
class Mathy {
    static yieldFibonacci(maxValue: number = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY): IterableIterator<number> {
        let current = 0
        let next = 1
        while (next < maxValue) {
            yield next
            [(current, next)] = [next, current + next]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Playground https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oQC5iwS2GgCoBzAUwDsyAnXea6ACgEoV0NoBPPMkAE2gBGANzsM3XgIBMojlx79oAZlnQAvqg2pg8ChHggyAOhDwSjANpHrCeEfJVaWeiwC6zIA

Answer (score 1):

```
class Mathy {
    static *yieldFibonacci(maxValue: number = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY): IterableIterator<number> {
        let current = 0
        let next = 1
        while (next < maxValue) {
            yield next
            ;[current, next] = [next, current + next]
        }
    }
}
```